# The parameter 'username' must not be empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory, asp.net-membership

I have create a method that should return an attributes soredin Active Directory for a logged in User using Membership.

I receive this error `The parameter 'username' must not be empty.` any idea how to solve it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Threading;

   public static string SetGivenNameUser()
    {
        string givenName = string.Empty;
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal userP = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user.UserName);
        if (userP != null)
            givenName = userP.GivenName;
        return givenName;
    }
```

STACK

```
ArgumentException: The parameter 'username' must not be empty.
Parameter name: username]
   System.Web.Util.SecUtility.CheckParameter(String& param, Boolean checkForNull, Boolean checkIfEmpty, Boolean checkForCommas, Int32 maxSize, String paramName) +2386569
   System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.CheckUserName(String& username, Int32 maxSize, String paramName) +30
   System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline) +86
   System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline) +63
   System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser() +19
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to see what the value of `user.UserName` is when you compile the code?  My guess is, it is `empty` or `null`.  Or, have you checked the value of `user` since you are setting it at `MembershipUser user = new Membership.GetUser()`?

Comment: shouldn't this line `UserPrincipal userP = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user.UserName);` actually be `userP = FindByIdentity(domain, IdentityType.Name, username);`

Comment: you need to pass the actual username.. what is the username that you are trying to find..? change your method to accept a Parameter `public static string SetGivenName(string username)` then call this  `UserPrincipal userP = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);`

Comment: you need to pass the samAccount Name so you could use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` if it has the domain\username you need to split that out to get the Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except when you just set authorization, in which case the httpcontext object needs to be reset, the most reliable way to get username is

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

so, refactoring your code would look like this:

```
UserPrincipal userP = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

Reason for this is, some objects have their own local 'hooks' into membership. And sometimes those hooks haven't been filled my the httpcontext object yet.

Answer (score 1):

I share the code which solved my problem. My issue was that I was calling SetGivenNameUser when the user was not logged in so I have to make an adjustment. Thanks all for your suggestions.

```
   public static string SetGivenNameUser()
    {
        string givenName = string.Empty;
        string currentUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        // If the USer is logged in
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentUser))
        {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            UserPrincipal userP = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user.UserName);
            if (userP != null)
                givenName = userP.GivenName;
        }
        return givenName;
    }
```